# Need to track down specific color line and get coordinates

Tags: javascript, python, screenshot, dearpygui, color-tracking

I need to place the mouse pointer in the specific point where I can perform some other functions after running some code.

I need to track down a specific color and get co-ordinates. I have attached a picture to clear it out. I am trying to do it in Python but I wonder if javascript could do this.[Here is the picture what I am looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkZG3.png). I am a beginner in this community and please excuse my english. :) Hope someone have a solution for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.